# How to make the return false if the arraylist already have the string present in class?

Tags: string, arraylist, duplicates

I'm new to coding.
How do I return a false if there is a string being added that's already in the arraylist?
For example, if you have a list of dog names in the class and you add new dog names in the list, but don't add it when the same dog name was already in the list?

Comment: please post your code for a personalised answer.

Answer (score 0):

## The Solution:

You could use a `for` statement to iterate through your array list:

```
public static bool checkArray(string dogName)
{
   for int i=0; i<arrayName.Length; i++) // basic for loop to go through whole array
   {
       if (arrayName[i] == dogName) //checks if array value at index i is the dog's name
       {
          return true; //if it is, return true
       }
   }
   return false; //gone through whole array, not found so return false
}
```

This means you can call your method via

```
 string Name = "myDogsName";
 bool isAlreadyPresent = checkArray(Name);
```

## Note

- This is written in C#, and so other coding languages will *slightly*
  differ in their syntax.
- `isAlreadyPresent` will then contain a bool value if the dog is
  present or not
- I have written this (for learning purposes) in (possibly) an
  inefficient way, but should allow you to understand what is happening
  at each stage.

---

## the i++

The `i++` may confuse new programmers, but effectively it is the same as writing

```
i = i + 1;
```

This also works for `i--`;

```
i = i - 1;
```

Or even `i*=2`;

```
i = i * 2;
```